# Сохранение игры в Unity. Как сохранять ссылочные типы, а потом загружать их?

Tags: unity3d

Например. Мне нужно сохранить все объекты на сцене, но у каждого объекта есть скрипт с полем.

```
public GameObject randomObject;
```

В котором может храниться любой объект на сцене. Который так же будет загружаться и иметь ссылки.

Каким способом мне сохранять связи между объектами при сохранении и загрузке?
То что мне пришло в голову, так это хранить id для каждого объекта на сцене.
Да и вообще в любом классе придётся хранить какой то порядковый номер. А после загрузки игры найти объекты по id.

Есть ли лучшее решение? Или ссылки на статьи по этой теме.

---

Я не могу сделать вот так (не могу сохранить ссылки на экземпляры классов в json)

```
    public class MyClass
    {
        public MyClass myClass;
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var myClass_1 = new MyClass();
            var myClass_2 = new MyClass();

            myClass_1.myClass = myClass_2;
            myClass_2.myClass = myClass_1;

            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myClass_1);
            Console.WriteLine(json);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Можно в отдельном скрипте создать словарь (ключ - объект, значение - значение переменной randomNumber) и в цикле пройтись по всем объектам сцены, записав все их значения в словарь. Пойсле этого словарь можно сериализовать

Comment: Гарантирую что затевается некий лютый костылище. Настоятельно советую изменить вопрос и расписать что ты хочешь получить. А то способ которым ты этого хочешь достичь просто ужасающе неправильный с вероятностью в 99.999%.

Comment: Советую изучить изучить принципы работы бинарной сериализации
https://habr.com/ru/post/242069/

Comment: @Andrew Просто я помню как в скайриме через консоль можно было увидеть id любого объекта в игре. Поэтому я подумал, может нужно сделать что то подобное.

Comment: не верю что они делали сериализацию всех обьектов на сцене)

Comment: Я ошибся, оказывается в unity можно сериализовать ссылки на объекты, производные от UnityEngine.Object, и так же можно получить их id.